# Why can't I send the class error further along with the chain?

Tags: ruby, rescue

I've got an error in some child class:

```
(byebug) e.class
CSV::MalformedCSVError
(byebug) e.message.truncate(150, omission: '')
"Illegal quoting in line 1. [SmarterCSV: csv line 1]"
(byebug) e
#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1. [SmarterCSV: csv line 1]>
(byebug) raise e.class, e.message.truncate(150, omission: '')
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

I want to send the original error class and message to a further class, to rescue all of them without the creation of custom error for each child class (`ChildClassError = Class.new(StandardError)`).

I will be grateful for the help. I would like to understand the reason.

What's wrong here?

```
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e.class
end
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
```

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin unfortunately, nope. thanks for the try.

Comment: I just want to understand, what's happened with `raise` method.

The simple solution is: 
    `raise ChildClassError, "#{e.class}: #{e.message.truncate(150, omission: '')}"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with [`CSV::MalformedCSVError#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/MalformedCSVError.html#method-c-new) violating the standard for the exceptions that [`Kernel#raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) expects.

The latter attempts to call `Exception#new/1` while the only possible arity of the constructor of `CSV::MalformedCSVError` is two. You should create an object yourself:

```
raise CSV::MalformedCSVError.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''), __LINE__)
```

For the generic case, you probably should [get the arity](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-arity) of the constructor and behave correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by just rescuing from `StandardError` exception like so:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

begin
  foo = Foo.new
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e.class.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''))
end
```

Though this way, you're reinitializing another object of the same class here with a new/modified message.

**Edit:** Aleksei made a good point on arity, as a custom error/exception classes are made differently to have fine-grained control over the exceptions that are helpful while debugging. Make sure you have the right arity otherwise you'd be on a goose hunt than solving actual problem.

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak : What's the message that you see in logs?

Comment: ```
   24:             byebug
=> 25:             raise e.class.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''))
   26:           end
   27:           pms_csv.imported!
   28:         end
   29: 
(byebug) raise e.class.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''))
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

nil
```

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak : Read the edit section, `e.class.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''))` where e.class is `CSV::MalformedCSVError` part which expects two arguments. `CSV::MalformedCSVError.`: `e.class.new(e.message.truncate(150, omission: ''), __LINE__)` should be used.